# Does ASP.NET Core Identity library have an option for CAPTCHA?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

In the ASP.NET Core Identity library, is there a way to have it require a CAPTCHA when a new user is registering?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't have built-in CAPTCHA functionality.

But you can use [`Blazor ReCaptcha`](https://github.com/tossnet/Blazor-Captcha) (Google CAPTCHA) to implement this requirement.

---

[image]